# How to project data into both a Vertical & Horizontal Coordinate System?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3

I have a shapefile whose Geometry is of `POINTZM` type.

The XY coordinate System is `NAD_1983_CORS96_StatePlane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200_Ft_US`
and the Z coordinate system is `North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988`

I want to transform the data, so that the data is projected in a Geographic (Lat/Long) projection, with the WGS84 horizontal datum and the EGM96 vertical datum.

I can't figure out how I can do this using the Project tool in ArcToolbox, of ArcGIS for Desktop 10.3.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Project tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm) has Vertical parameter since 10.4. The link also mentions that you need to install additional package with coordinate system data.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently not possible with ArcGIS for Desktop, see Esri's article [FAQ:  Are vertical datum transformations supported in ArcGIS?](http://support.esri.com/ja/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32337)

If you go to the [ArcGIS idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/apex/ideaView?id=08730000000bzDEAAY) page referenced in the article's comments, there is a mention of this being possible in Pro and Runtime, programmatically. To be verified with Esri, I couldn't find any confirmation of this.